# QueryDSL: convert list of BooleanExpression to Predicate

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm trying to create a query that would depend on number of boolean parameters. The function that creates the predicate looks like this:

```
Predicate createPredicate(Boolean param1, Boolean param2) {
    List<BooleanExpression> booleanExpressions = new List<>();        
    if (param1)
        booleanExpressions.add(/** expression 1 **/);
    if (param2)
        booleanExpressions.add(/** expression 2 **/);
    convertExpressionsToPredicate(booleanExpressions);
}
```

The problem is the `convertExpressionsToPredicate` function. Is there any special method in querydsl to join list of expressions into one predicate using the `or` operator?

The solution I'm looking for should convert this:

```
List<BooleanExpression> booleanExpressions = List(exp1, exp2, exp3);
```

into:

```
Predicate p = exp1.or(exp2).or(exp3)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To construct complex boolean expressions, use the `com.querydsl.core.BooleanBuilder` class. It implements `Predicate` and can be used in cascaded form. For example:

```
public List<Customer> getCustomer(String... names) {
    QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
    JPAQuery<Customer> query = queryFactory.selectFrom(customer);
    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    for (String name : names) {
        builder.or(customer.name.eq(name));
    }
    query.where(builder);
    return query.fetch();
}
```

`BooleanBuilder` is mutable and initially represents null. After each `and` or `or` call it represents the result of the operation.

Comment: Be aware that if given `names` is empty, the `BooleanBuilder()` stays initialized without any or-condition and the query would fetch all costumers. In that case however it should propably return no costumers. You can check with `!builder.hasValue()` and do an early return with empty list (or ofc. have a guard checking `names` the very first line for this example). I've not figured out a clean way to initialize the BooleanBuilder so it defaults to "false".

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is using Spring Boot JPA and QueryDSL, you can use the following to get a `Page<YourType>` result (in Kotlin):

```
fun listCards(page: Int?, pageSize: Int?, orderColumnName: String?, orderDirection: Sort.Direction?, filter: CardFilter?): Page<Card> {
  val pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page ?: 0, pageSize ?: 10, orderDirection ?: Sort.Direction.ASC, orderColumnName ?: Card::cardNumber.name)
  val conditions = BooleanBuilder()
  filter?.cardNumber?.let { qCard.cardNumber.contains(it) }?.let { conditions.and(it) }
  filter?.cardHolderName?.let { qCard.cardHolderName.containsIgnoreCase(it) }?.let { conditions.and(it) }
  filter?.phoneNumber?.let { qCard.phoneNumber.contains(it) }?.let { conditions.and(it) }
  filter?.email?.let { qCard.email.contains(it) }?.let { conditions.and(it) }
  filter?.locale?.let { qCard.locale.eq(it) }?.let { conditions.and(it) }

  if (conditions.hasValue()) {
    return cardRepository.findAll(conditions.value!!, pageRequest)
  }
  return cardRepository.findAll(pageRequest)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ExpressionUtils.allOf(ps) // use AND join conditions, ps is a list of predicate
ExpressionUtils.anyOf(ps) // use OR join conditions, ps is a list of predicate
```

Comment: When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide a significantly better explanation than existing answers.